# Postgres - Check if array contains values other than expected ones

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Say one entry has the array value {1, 2, 3}.

I want to be able to query this question:

"Does the array contain numbers other than 1 and 2?" (yes)

This would also work for my purposes:

"Does this array contain no values other than 1, 2, 3, and 4?" (yes - ok even though 4 isn't used)

I've looked around and haven't been able to find this particular variant of searching in an array. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Edit: I've hacked together a solution where I unnest the array, and select from the unnested rows to match my condition with an `!= ANY`, but it doesn't seem to be very elegant and I'm hoping there's an alternative!

Comment: Can you please explain the second condition?" Does this array contain no values other than 1, 2, and 4?" , how is it yes? Are you not referring to {1, 2, 3}?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I meant to say no. Edited

Comment: Actually I meant to pose that question totally differently. Changed the second question, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an option you could try using `EXCEPT` and `UNNEST`

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN count(*) > 0
            THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
        END IN_A_NOT_IN_B
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(array [1,2,3])
        EXCEPT
    SELECT unnest(array [1,2])
    ) t;
```

If you reverse it, your second condition would be True.